# SQL Server get count row interval next 5 seconds for every row with same criteria

Tags: sql-server, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

i have an example data :

[image]

I need to get the count of SNs for the next 5 seconds where the SNs are of the same type and the same selection

[image]

I tried using join but didn't quite get to the point. Is there a way to get this.

Comment: As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: SQL Server or Teradata?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from TestData t1
cross apply
(
  select
    count(*) [Count],
    isnull(string_agg(t2.SN, ','), '-') [Related SN]
  from TestData t2
  where
    t2.SN <> t1.SN
    and t2.Type = t1.Type
    and t2.Selection = t1.Selection
    and t2.DT >= t1.DT
    and datediff(second, t1.DT, t2.DT) < 5
) RelatedSN;
```